# c++ fstream not writing to object properly

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

I have the following code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // ========================================================================================
    // part a - initialiaze 100 records, lastName = "unassigned", firstName = "", age = 0
    ofstream outPerson_0("nameage.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

    // exit program if ofstream could not open file
    if (!outPerson_0)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } // end if

    Person blankPerson("unassigned", "", 0); // constructor zeros out each data member

    // output 100 blank records to file
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        outPerson_0.write(reinterpret_cast< const char * >(&blankPerson), sizeof(Person));

    // ========================================================================================
    // part b - input 10 first names and ages and write them to file
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int age;

    fstream outPerson_1("nameage.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    // exit program if fstream cannot open file
    if (!outPerson_1)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } // end if

    // iterate 10 times to get first names and ages
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // get user input
        cout << "Enter last name, first name and age (space separated): ";
        // set dummy values in object
        std::string s = std::to_string(i);
        blankPerson.setLastName(s);
        blankPerson.setFirstName(s);
        blankPerson.setAge(i);

        // seek position in file of user-specified record, using i
        auto pos = (i) * sizeof(Person);
        outPerson_1.seekp(pos);

        // write user-specified information in file
        outPerson_1.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&blankPerson), sizeof(Person));
    }
    // ========================================================================================
    // part c - update record with no info
}
```

Part a populated 100 objects with dummy values, and writes to file.  Part b updates the first 10 objects with dummy values generated by iterator i.  For some strange reason, part b does not work properly.  Could someone tell me why?  The result is exactly the same as when I run part a alone.

Comment: If you're holding the names in your Person class as std::strings or some other container, you can't just write to and read from a file in binary fashion. You need serialise them properly either yourself or by using a library. C++ standard library doesn't do this as far as I know.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Normally object is not suggested to write to file directly, but just by case, your code has other problem:
the **ofstream** and **fstream** instances have its own internal buffer, the data will be written into internal buffer before flushing/syncing to underlying file.

Before quitting the program,

1. ***fstream outPerson_1*** will destroyed
2. its internal buffer will be flushed to file "nameage.dat"
3. ***ofstream outPerson_0*** is destroyed
4. its internal buffer will be flushed to file "nameage.dat" again

   (as for why, it is another topic, don't talk here)

Since the data in outPerson_0 is more than the data in outPerson_1, so the outPerson_1 data is overwritten, and then you can't see it, if you write more data into outPerson_1, you will observe it.

There may be 2 options for your code:
Option#1:
flush the data after writing the first 100 person data

```
// output 100 blank records to file
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    outPerson_0.write(reinterpret_cast< const char * >(&blankPerson), sizeof(Person));
outPerson_0.flush();
```

Option#2:
Add ios::app flag to let ofstream/fstream to append the data to the file

```
ofstream outPerson_0("nameage.dat", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
fstream outPerson_1("nameage.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
```

Comment: Dear sir, I am grateful for your expert help.  I am following the book's examples and merging codes from it.  There is no mention of flush() in the chapter I am reading.  Before I dive into your solution, thank you so much.